# user input then show specific row data

Tags: python

```
ID  score  rank  Pass
512  80     5     Yes
11   12     255   No
115  44     70    Yes
345  61     177   No
 .   .       .     .
 .   .       .     .
```

I want to ask user to input his/her own ID number then she/he can see their own score, rank and Pass information.
Also, make sure they could only input number less than 1000.
I had 1000 data points of ID.

For example, I am asked to input ID then I key in 512.
It would display my score 80 rank 5 Pass Yes.
And if I input 1344 (or strings) it would be asked again until I input correct value.

I am a starter, I'll be very thankful if anyone would like to give me some suggestion :D

Comment: The first thing I would do is write a program that reads every line of your file and prints them all out.  This shouldn't take more than a couple of lines and once it is working you may see how to continue on your own, or at least have some code to ask a better, more detailed question here.

Comment: not quite understand what you meant. But my dataframe is kinda of large, up to 10000. So basically, I can't print them all out. 
And my purpose was trying to let user input their ID manually, once they did they can see their own score info. 
I had been setting up all the dataframe. I stuck on this input step for hours:(

Comment: What I meant to say is you have posted no code, show us that you tried something and what you have tried so we can better answer your question. Do you know how to read in a file? Have you heard of a for loop? Do you know Python is a programming language? The answer to any of these questions will change how I could best answer YOUR question.  I currently don't know any of these answers, but if you posted the code you have tried, I would know and would be better equipped to help you. ( See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask )

Comment: Thanks. I imported pandas and also read in a cvs file. So far, that’s how I set up my data frame. I was trying to use input as a dataframe row index. For example, input=input()  print(df[input(),2]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use the following logic

```
data = pd.read_csv('C:/random/d1',header=None,names=['ID','Score','rank','Pass'])
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
flag=True
while(flag):
    userIndex=int(input('Enter the ID: '))
    if(userIndex >=0 and userIndex <=1000):
        if(df[df['ID']==userIndex].empty):
            print('No records found, try again')
            continue
        else:
            print(df[df['ID']==userIndex])
            continue
    else:
        flag=False
        print('Out of range')
        break
```

## result

```
    ID  Score  rank Pass
0  512     80     5  Yes
1   11     12   255   No
2  115     44    70  Yes
3  345     61   177   No
Enter the ID: 512
    ID  Score  rank Pass
0  512     80     5  Yes
Enter the ID: 225
No records found, try again
Enter the ID: 11
   ID  Score  rank Pass
1  11     12   255   No
Enter the ID: 2500
Out of range
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use pandas, i have just created two columns in data frame

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 512, 1: 11, 2: 115, 3: 345},'score':{0:80,1:12,2:44,3:61}})
number = input ("Enter ID:")
if int(number)<1000:
  print(df[df['ID']==int(number)])
else:
  print('id is greater than 1000')
```